# Realm: In a one to many Relation ship, how to get the records based on a Category in this example

Tags: ios, swift, realm

User can create a Category and then add a Bookmark to a category

Here is the Category class

```
class Category: RLMObject {
 dynamic var name = ""
}
```

A one-to-many relationship is created by declaring the property of type RLMObject(Category)

```
class Bookmark: RLMObject {
  dynamic var name = ""    
  dynamic var category = Category()
}
```

There is an API to get all the Bookmarks like this:

```
Bookmark.allObjects().arraySortedByProperty("name", ascending: true)
```

I have created a Category with name "stackoverflow" and it has several bookmarks

Now I want to get all the Bookmarks belonging to a specific Category named "stackoverflow". How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
let category = Category.objectsWhere("name == 'stackoverflow'").firstObject() as! Category?
if let category = category {
    let bookmarks = category.linkingObjectsOfClass("Bookmark", forProperty: "category")
}
```